# ListFragment content changing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a simple MyListFragment fragment which shows one simple array of data on the screen.

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {   
      private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
      public ArrayAdapter<String> getAdapter() {
          return adapter;
      }
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            String[] values = new String[] {"data", "data", "data"};
           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);           
          }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

I wonder how can I change this data dynamically from my Activity? Please tell me if there is a simple way how to do this! I've tried but have failed...

UPD: I added a function changeContent to MyListFragment:

```
    public void changeContent(String[] value) {
        adapter.addAll(value);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
    }
}
```

As you see, adapter is a global variable and it's initialized inside onActivityCreated, but my program crashes because inside changeContent in equals null! I can't get why!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that changes your values variable and then once you have filled it with your new data just call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to fill your list with the new data.

Comment: Could you please say it more in detail?